# Android Studio cannot find default activity

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I've struggled with this for two days now.No matter what I do, Android Studio 2.1.1 , running on windows 10 64 keeps throwing

***Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity* .**

Also, syntax highlighting for java files isn't working either, i.e. my MainActivity.java file has no syntax checking at all.

I've had no luck with any SO answers which mainly included one or more of the below:

I've tried

1- Invalidating caches and restarting android studio

2- Cleaning/Rebuilding

3- Restarting windows

4- Completely removing android studio and reinstalling from scratch

5- Gradle resync

6- Trying to create new projects with varying SDKs just to get atleast one to build- none does

Any ideas why this is happening? For reference , my files are below

```
MainActivity.java:
package com.example.simpleapp.simpleapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml **( the .MainActivity is in red, it can't find that either)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.simpleapp.simpleapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle Project File

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Gradle Module file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.simpleapp.simpleapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that the complete mainfest? if so, then it's missing something along the lines of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx.yourpackage"
    android:installLocation="auto">`

Comment: @MikeT it isn't missing

Comment: Have you tried using the Gradle Lint task?

Comment: `activity android:name="com.example.simpleapp.simpleapp.MainActivity"`

Comment: Checked path variables if on windows?

Comment: Do a clean build or file->invalidate caches / and restart

Comment: just try to create another launcher activity . from file/new/activity/emptyActivity and select that activity to be a launcher activity and remove mainActivity .

Comment: @alimohammadi _6- Trying to create new projects with varying SDKs just to get atleast one to build- none does_

Comment: Just created a new project and copied your MainActivity and activity part of the manifest (created a minimal activity_main XML) and it ran fine. Gradles both match (old eyes permitting :) ). So I believe it's something in Studio that is amiss.

Answer (score 1):

Give total path of your .MainActivity in Manifest.xml file

```
   <activity android:name="com.example.simpleapp.simpleapp.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This based upon:-

Default launcher activity defined here and that will be pointing to android:name tag where MainActivty exist.When ever activity tad does n't found in manifest it will through "Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error while Launching activity" .User might be changed the package in middle will cause this issue

Comment: Could you please explain how/why that would fix the issue? Especially considering that in general the full name isn't provided.

Comment: default launcher activity defined here and that will be pointing to android:name tag where MainActivty exist.When ever activity tad does n't found in manifest it will through "Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error while Launching activity" .User might be changed the package in middle will cause this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I tried that before actually. It just turns the "MAIN" to red, indicating it can't find the symbol

Answer (score 1):

OK after many frustrating hours, I discovered that somehow `"MainActivity.java"` got added as a recognized file type. No idea how, but as the default name for all activities added with `Add->New Activity` wizard is `"MainActivity"`, android studio always treated `"MainActivity.java"` as jsp. So every time I added a new activity , it could **never** find the main activity!

I went to File -> Settings -> Editor -> FileTypes and removed "MainActivity.java" in the right hand pane under "Recognized File Types".

[image: Screenshot showing Recognized File Types box]

This fixed the problem. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was `MainActivity.java` not identifying as class.

I went to File -> Settings -> Editor -> FileTypes and removed "MainActivity.java" in the right hand pane under "Recognized File Types".

in my case it was in txt file types.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in the Manifest file. In my case, I did some refactoring that affected the 'activity' tags, (after changing a variable 'activity' into 'mActivity'), that's why it could not find the launcher Activity.