# Error running wear default device not found

Tags: android, xml, manifest

I've created an android application and am now getting an "Error running wear, default device not found" error message. I can't think of anything I have done or changed that has made this start.

I have closed Android studio and re opened it
I've invalidated the caches and restarted 
I've run a lint check 
Looked at this question [Android Studio cannot find default activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607118/android-studio-cannot-find-default-activity)

Still no joy however.

My manifest is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.james.testing">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".ScrollingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".SimpleGridActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Drinks"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Food"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".Fitness"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the theme to something basic for now and see if it works.

Comment: Changed to theme.appCompat, no change

Comment: Ok, why are there so many default main activities? There should be one main default activity which would start upon running the app and the other classes can be called without making them default classes. So, you can take out the intent launcher main from the other child activities and keep the main launcher for the main one. Give that a try maybe?

Comment: Try adding <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> to one of your activities